# MockServer with IPv6

Tags: ipv6, mockserver, mockserver-netty

I'm running a client issuing some request against [MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/). When calling MockServer with its IPv4 address everything works well but when calling it via IPv6 MockServer throws an exception:

```
    021-07-23 13:57:39 5.11.1 SEVERE 8889 exception processing request:

  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "path" : "/mypath",
    "headers" : {
      "Host" : [ "[2a01:c22:cc09:b600:50e7:2959:9dda:7aa8]:8889" ],
      "User-Agent" : [ "Go-http-client/1.1" ],
      "Accept-Encoding" : [ "gzip" ],
      "content-length" : [ "0" ]
    },
    "keepAlive" : true,
    "secure" : true
  }

 error:

  For input string: "c22"
 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c22"
       at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
       at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
       at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
       at org.mockserver.model.HttpRequest.socketAddressFromHostHeader(HttpRequest.java:1036)
       at org.mockserver.client.NettyHttpClient.sendRequest(NettyHttpClient.java:70)
       at org.mockserver.mock.action.http.HttpActionHandler.processAction(HttpActionHandler.java:216)
       at org.mockserver.netty.HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(HttpRequestHandler.java:151)
       at org.mockserver.netty.HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(HttpRequestHandler.java:48)
       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at org.mockserver.dashboard.DashboardWebSocketHandler.channelRead(DashboardWebSocketHandler.java:141)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at org.mockserver.closurecallback.websocketregistry.CallbackWebSocketServerHandler.channelRead(CallbackWebSocketServerHandler.java:55)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at org.mockserver.netty.unification.PortUnificationHandler.switchToHttp(PortUnificationHandler.java:260)
       at org.mockserver.netty.unification.PortUnificationHandler.decode(PortUnificationHandler.java:138)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:366)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1518)
       at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1267)
       at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1314)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

It looks like MockServer has some issues parsing host and port. Is it even possible to use MockServer with IPv6?

Comment: An IPv6 address has eight 16-bit words, but you have nine 16-bit words, so it is an invalid IPv6 address.

Comment: The last one is the port

Comment: Then you are not following the RFCs and surrounding the address part with square brackets (`[]`),

Comment: You're right, but even if I add bracket the exception still occurs. See the updated stack trace in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are RFCs that explain you surround the IPv6 address in square brackets (`[` and `]`) when you use a port, or in a URI. For example, *[RFC 4038, Application Aspects of IPv6 Transition](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4038)*:

> **[5.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4038#section-5.1). Presentation Format for an IP Address**
>
> Many applications use IP addresses to identify network nodes and to
> establish connections to destination addresses.  For instance, using
> the client/server model, clients usually need an IP address as an
> application parameter to connect to a server.  This IP address is
> usually provided in the presentation format, as a string.  There are
> two problems when porting the presentation format for an IP address:
> the allocated memory and the management of the presentation format.
>
> Usually, the memory allocated to contain an IPv4 address
> representation as a string is unable to contain an IPv6 address.
> Applications should be modified to prevent buffer overflows made
> possible by the larger IPv6 address.
>
> IPv4 and IPv6 do not use the same presentation format.  IPv4 uses a
> dot (.) to separate the four octets written in decimal notation, and
> IPv6 uses a colon (:) to separate each pair of octets written in
> hexadecimal notation [RFC3513].  In cases where one must be able to
> specify, for example, port numbers with the address (see below), it
> may be desirable to require placing the address inside the square
> brackets [TextRep].
>
> A particular problem with IP address parsers comes when the input
> is    actually a combination of IP address and port number.  With IPv4
> these are often coupled with a colon; for example, "192.0.2.1:80".
> However, this approach would be ambiguous with IPv6, as colons are
> already used to structure the address.
>
> Therefore, the IP address parsers that take the port number
> separated    with a colon should distinguish IPv6 addresses somehow.
> One way is    to enclose the address in brackets, as is done with
> Uniform Resource    Locators (URLs) [RFC2732]; for example,
> http://[2001:db8::1]:80.
>
> Some applications also need to specify IPv6 prefixes and lengths:
> The prefix length should be inserted outside of the square brackets,
> if used; for example, [2001:db8::]/64 or 2001:db8::/64 and not
> [2001:db8::/64].  Note that prefix/length notation is syntactically
> indistinguishable from a legal URI; therefore, the prefix/length
> notation must not be used when it isn't clear from the context that
> it's used to specify the prefix and length and not, for example, a
> URI.
>
> In some specific cases, it may be necessary to give a zone
> identifier    as part of the address; for example, fe80::1%eth0.  In
> general,    applications should not need to parse these identifiers.
>
> The IP address parsers should support enclosing the IPv6 address in
> brackets, even when the address is not used in conjunction with a
> port number.  Requiring that the user always give a literal IP
> address enclosed in brackets is not recommended.
>
> Note that some applications may also represent IPv6 address
> literals    differently; for example, SMTP [RFC2821] uses
> [IPv6:2001:db8::1].
>
> Note that the use of address literals is strongly discouraged for
> general-purpose direct input to the applications.  Host names and DNS
> should be used instead.

That would change the line where you use the address:

```
  "Host" : [ "[2a01:c22:cc09:b600:81fb:91fe:4788:d52d]:8889" ],
```

Comment: Already tried this but I still get the same exception. See the updated stack track in my question.